# Android Service guarantees

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle

In Android, can we guarantee that a background service will NEVER be killed by the OS if its bounded client is in the foreground?

I am almost certain that this is true, but I can't find the documentation to prove it.

Comment: Yes, when service is bounded to foreground activity, service shouldn't be killed.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand in here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection.html#onServiceDisconnected(android.content.ComponentName)

The bound service can be killed by the system, however the activity is not unbounded. It will bounded once the service becomes available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bind flag `Context.BIND_ABOVE_CLIENT`. In this case your service will be killed only **after** the foreground client.
But according to docs:

> this is not guaranteed